# How to configure .csv table rates weight

Tags: magento-2.1, table-rates

I will set the delivery cost depending on the weight of the product.

I have created the tablerates.csv file on generator: https://www.elgentos.nl/tablerates/

I need to configure it in this way(sample):

---

- **Country:** Czech Republic
- **Total order basket weight:** 50kgs
- **Delivery cost to the Czech republic for order 50kgs:** 300 euro

---

- **Country:** Poland
- **Total order basket weight:** 50kgs
- **Delivery cost to Poland for order 50kgs:** 100 euro

Can anyone help set up my file tablerates.csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the calculation condition of Table rates shipping method to: Weight vs Destination.
2. Prepare the data in CSV format like this:

[image]

Notice that you need to specify the price for below 50 kg and for 50+ kg.

In this example your price is set for Czech Republic to 300€ for 50 kg AND above.

You can check the full documentation in Magento's docs here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!